# JSF: error handling with <error-page> and JSF1073 error

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, error-handling

I have an `error-page` directive which redirect all exception to an error display page

My `web.xml`:

```
<web-app [...]>
    [...]
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
        <location>/view/error.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

**It works for almost any exception** but today I noticed that sometimes and JSF error is logged and the exception is not handled (i.e., there is no redirection to the error page).

Here what I have in the log:

```
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context || JSF1073: javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException caught during processing of INVOKE_APPLICATION 5 : UIComponent-ClientId=searchForm:j_idt147, Message=/view/listView.xhtml @217,7 actionListener="#{listController.nextPageClicked}": java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context || /view/listView.xhtml @217,7 actionListener="#{listController.nextPageClicked}": java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: /view/listView.xhtml @217,7 actionListener="#{listController.nextPageClicked}": java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:182)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:600)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ch.ethz.id.wai.web.controller.ListController.nextPageClicked(ListController.java:410)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

How can I also handle these exceptions?

**Edit**: by *handle* I don't mean that I want to correct the problem causing the exception (which is another topic) but my question is how can I catch the exception in JSF with the `<error-page>` directive. An error page is visible, an entry in the log can be easily missed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is by design. When an `actionListener` method throws an exception, it will only be logged and not thrown. It's "just" a listener intented for trivial preprocessing/logging tasks and such, not a real action. Only when an `action` method throws an exception, it will be delegated all the way to the container and end up in the default error page.

If you want to perform exception-sensitive business actions, do it in the `action` method instead.

#### See also:

- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener)